# Difference between functions in platform_driver and *_ops structures

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, ahci

If we take an ahci driver as an example.
In ahci_platform.c there are some driver functions described under:

```
static struct platform_driver ahci_driver = {...functions...}.
```

The question is:
What's the difference between functions described under `platform_driver` structure and functions described under `*_ops` (`ahci_ops` as an example)?

From my understanding, functions in the `platform_driver` structure are usually called automatically when loading/unloading the driver as an example. 
Functions described in `*_ops` are more user-accessible functions. Is that correct?

Comment: They are completely independent features. `struct platform_driver` tells Linux driver model, that certain driver is *class* of *platform*. ACHI operations are local to the AHCI library. They may or may not be user visible (what do you mean by this, btw?).